# How to pass the returned Image of an AsyncImage object to a different view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, mobile, swiftui

I need to pass the Image of an AsyncImage to another SwiftUI View that is the destination of a NavigationLink.

I am currently using an AsyncImage for the List cell and another one for the detail screen, but this of course causes the same image to load asynchronously twice, Id like to tap the List cell item and push to the Detail View with the already loaded image so I don't have to load it again.

What Im currently doing on CellView:

```
AsyncImage(url:  URL(string: movieStringUrl ?? "")) { image in
            image.resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            
            } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
    }
```

On ContentView:

```
ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
                NavigationLink(destination: MovieDetailView(movie: movie, viewModel: viewModel)) {
                    CellView(movie: movie, viewModel: viewModel)
                }
            }
```

On detail view:

```
AsyncImage(url:  URL(string: movieStringUrl ?? "")) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
```

Id like to be able to pass the regular Image object (not AsyncImage) to the detail view so I can avoid having to load the same image twice, but since the Image is in a closure, Im not quite sure how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: It'll be interesting to see if someone has a way to solve this with just the built-in `AsyncImage`, but my suspicion is that you'll have to write your own implementation  to do this.

Comment: Yeah, ideally id like to just use the built in AsyncImage and avoid writing a custom solution. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I had a similar issue. I solved it by dropping AsyncImage completely; instead, I did what @jnpdx suspected: I wrote the implementation to download the image using `.task{ }` and passed it to a variable in my view model.

Comment: Yeah that's actually pretty good, I figured there was some sort of way to do it with AsyncImage though.

Comment: `AsyncImage` is very convenient at times, but a custom solution is just a few lines of code and is a lot more flexible.
Let's see if there is a solution with AsyncImage.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncImage uses the shared URLSession so sou could set a `URLCache` on your `URLSession` then it won't be downloaded again, just read from the cache. It can either be a memory or disk cache.

Edit: there is a default cache so you probably don’t have to do anything and it’ll just work.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example with code? Im not using URLSession at all for images, Im straight up using AsyncImages.

Comment: AsyncImage uses URLSession

Comment: Makes sense. Not sure how would I go about messing with it though.